# Compressible fluid equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, flow, continuum-mechanics

We know the continuity equation of a continuum (in this case I want to discuss fluids, [equation reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation)):

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \nabla . (\rho u) = 0$$

where $\rho$ is the mass density of the fluid, $u$ is its velocity.

If it had a constant density, then equation becomes:

$$ \nabla . u = 0$$

My confusion is about another equation that concerns incompressible fluid, and somehow I think it is related to the continuity equation because it has the velocity divergence term. I found the equation in the [research paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/369974506_Homogenization_of_peristaltic_flows_in_piezoelectric_porous_media?_tp=eyJjb250ZXh0Ijp7ImZpcnN0UGFnZSI6InF1ZXN0aW9uIiwicGFnZSI6InByb2ZpbGUifX0). The equation is:

$$\gamma \dot{p} + \nabla . u = 0$$

where $\gamma$ is the fluid compressibility, $\dot{p}$ is the time derivative of the pressure, and $u$ is its velocity.

I tried to look for a derivation, but I couldn't find until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write density $\rho$ as a function of pressure $P$ and entropy $s$,
\begin{equation}
  \rho(P, s) \ ,
\end{equation}
being every thermodynamic quantity a field, function of space and time.

Thus, it's possible to write differential, time derivative, and gradient of the density as a derivative of composite function, as
\begin{equation}
 d \rho = \left(\dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial P}\right)_s d  P + \left(\dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial s}\right)_P d  s \\
  \partial_t \rho = \left(\dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial P}\right)_s \partial_t P + \left(\dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial s}\right)_P \partial_t s \\
 \nabla \rho = \left(\dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial P}\right)_s \nabla P + \left(\dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial s}\right)_P \nabla s \\
\end{equation}
Recalling the definition of isentropic compressibility
\begin{equation}
  \beta := \dfrac{1}{\rho}\left(\dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial P} \right)_s \ ,
\end{equation}
and inserting in the continuity equation, recasted in the convective form (introducing the material derivative $D_t \_ = \partial_t \_ + \mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla \_$)
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  0 & = \partial_t \rho + \nabla \cdot (\rho \mathbf{u}) = \\
& = \partial_t \rho +  \mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla \rho + \rho \nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = \\
& = D_t \rho + \rho \nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} \ ,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
we get
\begin{equation}
 0 = \left(\dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial P}\right)_s D_t P + \left(\dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial s}\right)_P D_t s + \rho \nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} \ .
\end{equation}
**Assuming constant and uniform entropy**, $D_t s \equiv 0$, and dividing by $\rho \ne 0$, we get
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
 0 & = \dfrac{1}{\rho} \left(\dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial P}\right)_s D_t P  + \nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = \\
 & = \beta D_t P + \nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}